# Spring boot classpath: The specified resource does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using h2 as a database for testing. I have added sql scripts to `/src/main/resources` but spring boot always fails with "**The specified resource does not exist.**" error.
Following are the configurations

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:data.sql
```

ErrorTrace: https://paste.ee/p/1kHwd

I have referred many posts on this platform and tried changing the path to classpath:/data.sql but this did not work as well. I am facing the same issue with the flyway. Somehow Spring can not found these scripts in resources.

Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i don't see spring.datasource.url, where spring find the h2 database, how find spring the databse?

Comment: Configuations looks ok. Spring can detect schema and data files if present in the resources folder with following `spring.datasource.schema=classpath:schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:data.sql`
Could you share the error trace?

Comment: @harry I have added the error trace.

Comment: @sourheart it is right on the top.

Comment: try to add ```  <resource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>``` in your pom file

Comment: @DmitriiBykov Thanks a lot man, this was set as <directory>src/main/resources</directory>. After using your solution, it totally worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add

```
   <resource> 
       <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory> 
   </resource>
```

in your pom file